# Retrieve email from People or Group Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, email, person

I have People or Group Field

Normally I retrieve value of fields as:

```
var fieldUsuario = ctx.CurrentItem.Notificar_x0020_a
```

But now I dont want text value, I debbug it and it have email in span as:

```
<span class="ms-entity-resolved" id="Notificar_x0020_a_084ffd45-b361-458e-b55f-c824ba8995ec_$ClientPeoplePicker_i:0#.f|membership|email@mydomain.com_ProcessedUser0_UserDisplay" title="User, SubName" style="max-width: 331px;">User, SubName</span>
```

As you can see it have: `email@mydomain.com` I want to retrieve this value. How can I achieve it? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following script to find Email Address of the People Picker Value.
if we have field name **"Manager"** with People Picker type then:

```
var arrEmailID = [];
var fieldName = "Manager";
var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
var emailSpan = $(_PeoplePicker).find('.sp-peoplepicker-userSpan');
if(emailSpan.length > 0) {
        $(emailSpan).each(function (){
            var _sid = $(this).attr('sid');
            arrEmailID.push(_sid);
            alert(_sid.split("|")[2]);
        })
}
else {
       alert("null");
}
console.log(arrEmailID);
```

**Reference:** https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5e244f77-106b-4d26-8d8e-a1b5514489ec/get-people-picker-valueemail-id-on-sharepoint-online-edit-form

Comment: Omg incredible, how about if field have more than one email, I mean multi select. How can I get two email values? is it possible?

Comment: Hi David, Check the updated code, this will work for multiple values too.

Comment: it looking for bot correctly but how can I  save it in variable and separate them by commas? for example `field: var fieldUsuario = _sid;`, and foreach  email  add to fieldUsuario with a comma for example `user1@onmicrosoft.com,user2@onmicrosoft`

Comment: David, please check the updated code.